# Using boost::recursive_variant with std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a `std::unordered_map` with a `boost::variant` as key and with integer as value. I'm trying to make this work:

```cpp
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

enum Token {};

struct AssignExpr;
struct LiteralExpr;

using Expr = boost::variant<boost::blank, 
                            boost::recursive_wrapper<AssignExpr>,
                            boost::recursive_wrapper<LiteralExpr>>;

using Literal = int;

struct LiteralExpr {
  Literal literal;

  explicit LiteralExpr(const Literal &literal);
};

struct AssignExpr {
  Token name;
  Expr value;

  AssignExpr(const Token &name, const Expr &val);
};

int main() {
  LiteralExpr li{0};
  AssignExpr ae{{}, li};

  std::unordered_map<Expr, std::size_t> m_locals{{li, 10}, {ae, 20}};
}
```

I tried to add `operator==` and an hash function but [get](https://godbolt.org/z/ajc74b61z) a linkage error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using  a hash-based container, all the element types must be hashable **and** equality comparable.

Boost variant implements hashing in terms of the ADL custoimization point `hash_value` - which by defaults uses `boost::hash<T>{}`. This means the easiest way to get the hashability is to implement `hash_value` for all types - including `boost::blank`.

Next up, let's default the `operator==`

```
bool operator==(LiteralExpr const&) const = default;
bool operator==(AssignExpr const&) const = default;
```

Or, if your compiler is hip enough, three-way comparison in one go:

```
auto operator<=>(LiteralExpr const&) const = default;
auto operator<=>(AssignExpr const&) const = default;
```

Then it all compiles, and better runs without incurring UB. Make sure your hash agrees with the equality relation!

**[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qY1P4Wf6b)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

namespace boost {
    [[maybe_unused]] static inline size_t hash_value(boost::blank) { return 0; }
} // namespace boost

namespace MyLib {
    using boost::hash_value;

    enum Token {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H};

    [[maybe_unused]] static constexpr auto name_of(Token tok) {
        return tok["ABCDEFGH"];
    }

    struct AssignExpr;
    struct LiteralExpr;

    using Expr = boost::variant<                //
        boost::blank,                           //
        boost::recursive_wrapper<AssignExpr>,   //
        boost::recursive_wrapper<LiteralExpr>>; //

    using Literal = int;

    struct LiteralExpr {
        Literal literal;

        explicit LiteralExpr(Literal literal) : literal(literal) {}

        auto operator<=>(LiteralExpr const&) const = default;
        friend size_t hash_value(LiteralExpr const& le) {
            return hash_value(le.literal);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LiteralExpr const& le) {
            return os << le.literal;
        }
    };

    struct AssignExpr {
        Token name;
        Expr  value;

        AssignExpr(Token name, Expr val) : name(name), value(std::move(val)) {}

        auto operator<=>(AssignExpr const&) const = default;
        friend size_t hash_value(AssignExpr const& ae) {
            auto h = hash_value(ae.name);
            boost::hash_combine(h, hash_value(ae.value));
            return h;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, AssignExpr const& ae) {
            return os << name_of(ae.name) << " := " << ae.value;
        }
    };

} // namespace MyLib

#define FMT_DEPRECATED_OSTREAM
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
template <> struct fmt::formatter<MyLib::Expr> {
    auto parse(auto& ctx) const { return ctx.begin(); }
    auto format(MyLib::Expr const& e, auto& ctx) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(
            [&](auto const& el) { return format_to(ctx.out(), "Expr({})", el); },
            e);
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace MyLib;

    LiteralExpr li{42};
    AssignExpr  ae{D, li};

    std::unordered_map<Expr, std::size_t> m_locals{{li, 10}, {ae, 20}};

    fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(m_locals, "\n"));
}
```

Prints

```
(Expr(D := 42), 20)
(Expr(42), 10)
```

### Side Notes

I'd simplify. `LiteralExpr` doesn't add anything over `Literal` (and certainly doesn't recurse).

Skip the `blank` unless you really need that capability (which would usually be something like `Null` in your AST).

All your structs seem they could be aggregates, so perhaps just enjoy aggregate construction.

```
struct Nil {
    friend constexpr size_t hash_value(Nil) { return 0; }
    constexpr bool operator==(Nil) const { return true; }
};

using Literal = int;

struct AssignExpr;
using Expr = boost::variant<               //
    Nil,                                   //
    Literal,                               //
    boost::recursive_wrapper<AssignExpr>>; //

enum Token {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H};

struct AssignExpr {
    Token name;
    Expr  value;
};
```

And you might homogenize the equality and hash operations a bit:

```
auto key() const { return std::tie(name, value); }

bool operator==(AssignExpr const& rhs) const { return key() == rhs.key(); }
friend size_t hash_value(AssignExpr const& ae) { return hash_value(ae.key()); }
```

This makes it so that the two **cannot** get out of sync.

Now it becomes **[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o6YYd1Pbn)**, 25 lines shorter and more capable:

```
(Expr(Nil), 30)
(Expr(D := 42), 20)
(Expr(42), 10)
```